# List of Notebooks in a Workspace - Databricks

Tags: databricks

I want to list down the Notebooks in a folder in Databricks.
I tried to use the utilities like , `dbutils.fs.ls("/path")` - > It shows the path of the storage folder.

I also tried to check `dbutil.notebook.help()` - nothing useful.

Lets say, there is a folder - `XXYY`. This folder contains multiple Notebooks. I just want the list of the Notebooks in that folder. Is their any command available. Any suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

`dbutils.fs.ls` works with files on the Databricks File System, so you can't use it.

You can get what you need via the the [List command of Workspaces REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace.html#list) - you can call your local workspace with something like this (this code doesn't include parsing of the output):

```py
import requests
ctx = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext()
host_name = ctx.tags().get("browserHostName").get()
host_token = "your_PAT_token"

response = requests.post(
    f'https://{host_name}/api/2.0/workspace/list',
    headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {host_token}'},
    data = {'path': '<your-path>'}
  ).json()
# add parsing of output here
```

Or you can use `databricks workspace ls` [command from databricks-cli](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/workspace-cli.html#list-objects-in-a-workspace).